# change the code to save file into database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 app and this code for saving file to folder, but I want to save the file into database.

Here is my model and controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace FileUpload.MVC.Models
{
    public class FileDetails
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Path { get; set; }
    }

    public class FilesViewModel
    {
        public List<FileDetails> Files { get; set; }
            = new List<FileDetails>();
    }

    public class TestController : Controller
    { 
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public TestController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            // Get files from the server
            var model = new FilesViewModel();

            foreach (var item in Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "upload")))
            {
                model.Files.Add(
                    new FileDetails { Name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(item), Path = item });
            }

            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(IFormFile[] files)
        {
            // Iterate each files
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                // Get the file name from the browser
                var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

                // Get file path to be uploaded
                var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "upload", fileName);

                // Check If file with same name exists and delete it
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
                {
                    System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);
                }

                // Create a new local file and copy contents of uploaded file
                using (var localFile = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(filePath))
                using (var uploadedFile = file.OpenReadStream())
                {
                    uploadedFile.CopyTo(localFile);
                }
            }

            ViewBag.Message = "Files are successfully uploaded";

            // Get files from the server
            var model = new FilesViewModel();
            foreach (var item in Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "upload")))
            {
                model.Files.Add(
                    new FileDetails { Name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(item), Path = item });
            }

            return View(model);
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> Download(string filename)
        {
            if (filename == null)
                return Content("filename is not availble");

            var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "upload", filename);

            var memory = new MemoryStream();
            using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
            {
                await stream.CopyToAsync(memory);
            }
            memory.Position = 0;
            return File(memory, GetContentType(path), Path.GetFileName(path));
        }

        private string GetContentType(string path)
        {
            var types = GetMimeTypes();
            var ext = Path.GetExtension(path).ToLowerInvariant();
            return types[ext];
        }

        private Dictionary<string, string> GetMimeTypes()
        {
            return new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {".txt", "text/plain"},
                {".pdf", "application/pdf"},
                {".doc", "application/vnd.ms-word"},
                {".docx", "application/vnd.ms-word"},
                {".xls", "application/vnd.ms-excel"},
                {".xlsx", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"},
                {".png", "image/png"},
                {".jpg", "image/jpeg"},
                {".jpeg", "image/jpeg"},
                {".gif", "image/gif"},
                {".csv", "text/csv"}
            };
        }

        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the problem with your existing code?

Answer (score 0):

In general, we will save the file to the database in the form of `byte[]`, You can follow this simple demo.

Model

```
public class MyFile
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }

        public byte[] Data { get; set; }
    }
```

DbContext

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<MyFile> files { get; set; }
    
    }
```

Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
        private readonly MyDbContext _dbContext;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, MyDbContext dbContext)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _dbContext = dbContext;
        }


      //.......

            [HttpPost]
            public IActionResult Index(IFormFile[] files)
            {
                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    if (file.Length > 0)
                    {
                        using (var memorySteam = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            file.CopyTo(memorySteam);
    
                            var File = new MyFile()
                            {
                                FileName = file.FileName,
                                Data = memorySteam.ToArray()
                            };
                            _dbContext.files.Add(File);
                            _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    
                        }
                    }
    
                }
                return View();
            }

    }
```

You can also refer to this [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-3.1#file-upload-scenarios-1).

Update========================

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">
        <span>Select File:</span>
        <input type="file" id="file" name="files" multiple onchange="Upload()"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
        <br/>
        <div id="fileList">
        </div>
        <br />
        <span style="color:green">@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Message)</span>
    </form>

@section scripts{
    <script>
        function Upload(){
            var input = document.getElementById('file');
            var output = document.getElementById('fileList');
            var children = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; ++i) {
                children += '<li>' + input.files.item(i).name + '</li>';
            }
            output.innerHTML = '<ul>' + children + '</ul>';
        }
    </script>
}
```

Demo
[image]

Update=====================================

Browser needs a [HttpGet] action to load the view. In your controller, It only has a [httppost] action, So it can't find the view in your project and it will report 404 error. Because i don't what you want to do before browser load the page, SO i don't write this [httpget] action in my answer. You just need to add this [httpGet] action in your controller and 404 error will be fixed:

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

In the view, check my answer:

```
<input type="file" id="file" name="files" multiple onchange="Upload()"/>
```

I set a property (name="files") in this input tag and in controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(IFormFile[] files){xxxx}
```

I also set the parameter  name as `files`. Because model binding is based on the model's name, input and parameter have the same name, So they can bind value successfully. Of course you can refer a model in the view, But in this case, I think set name is more simple.

Comment: HI @hhaannyy, I have updated my answer, It will fit your requirement. If this answer can help you solve this issue, Can you mark it as the answer? Thank you so much! [how to mark the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: Dear Mr Xinran Shen many thanks for your help , Unfortunately, the page did not open. I think we should add something inside the controller and We should also refer to the model in the View. Excuse me, I'm still a beginner.

Comment: The code i provided is a simple demo, I have tested and it works fine, Please share your current controller and view code, I can help you to find the error.

Comment: this is the link for model and controller and View      https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-2ng3pFvddJpjrpnCpI6HJP-gnC7bTEW/view?usp=share_link

Comment: Sorry, Can you explain what `the page did not open` means? when you load index view, It show any error?

Comment: yes the error " page not found"

Comment: sorry i tried but i cant

Comment: is the controller only as your post or i sholud add   public IActionResult Index() but how so please see the link out my data .... please

Comment: Dear Mr. Xinran Shen, I am very sorry for your inconvenience and thank you very much for your response. I have done everything as you sent, but the result is not good. When choosing a file, it appears twice, one at the bottom of  choose a file and the other next to it, and when I click on Upload, both disappear and I cannot download it.
The table name is files, the model name is Myfile.